# Why sudo could not get the right PATH environment?

Tags: scripts

I run command `sudo hadoop fs -ls /`, it said hadoop command is not found. But I have already set it in `/etc/profile`, and also I verify it by switch to user root.

What happens here ?

Comment: What does 'which hadoop' return?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make a sudoers.d file for sudo to permanently keep your environment variables.

> **CAUTION!** This method uses the sudoers file, you might get locked out by sudo if anything goes wrong. Proceed with caution.

1. `cd ~/Desktop`
2. `touch 'myfile'`
3. Open the file in an editor.
4. Add these lines (both blank lines mentioned below are very important):

   ```
   <This must be a blank line>
   Defaults env_keep += "your_variable_name_within_quotes"
   <This must be a blank line>
   ```
5. `sudo chmod 440 'myfile'`
6. `sudo mv 'myfile' '/etc/sudoers.d/myfile'`
7. Now open : `'/etc/sudoers'` and make sure there's the line: `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`
8. If it isn't there, **DO NOT EDIT IT**, instead do `sudo visudo`
9. Append the line at the end and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save it.
10. Restart and try a sudo command with that environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

cron uses its own default PATH, something like `/bin:/usr/bin`. See the [cron(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/cron.8.html) and [crontab(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/crontab.5.html) man pages.